Relevance of International Operations Advisory Group Spacecraft Emergency Cross Support Working Group SOP
How readily do mission teams currently rely on the work done by the International Operations Advisory Group Spacecraft Emergency Cross Support Working Group Standard Operating Process and Procedure document to inform anomaly/spacecraft emergency resolution?
I have linked the document here: https://www.ioag.org/Public%20Documents/IOAG%20SECSWG%20SOP%20Baseline%20-20191203.pdf
There are many service types and standards regarding CCSDS services. Do current commercial or government missions utilize this advisory group's work in designing their spacecraft and off-nominal operational procedures?
